# Soap API Python code to add new workday account (Operations:Add_Workday_Account)

Tags: python, workday-api

I am trying to add new workday account using python zeep module, can anyone help..

```py
message = client.service.Add_Workday_Account('Human_ResourcesService', 'Add_Workday_Account',
                                                 {'User_Name':'....', 'Password':'....'}, xml)
```

Comment: Maybe you can add an example of your data

Comment: can you mention all params passing to ``Add_Workday_Account``

Answer (score 0):

Please use the below code snippet.

Note: it use [zeep](https://docs.python-zeep.org/en/master/)

```
header = xsd.Element(
            '{urn:com.workday/bsvc}Workday_Common_Header',
            xsd.ComplexType([
                xsd.Element(
                    '{urn:com.workday/bsvc}Include_Reference_Descriptors_In_Response',
                    xsd.Boolean()),
            ])
        )
        workday_common_header = header(Include_Reference_Descriptors_In_Response=True)
        client_human_resource.service.Add_Workday_Account(_soapheaders=[workday_common_header],
                                                          Workday_Account_for_Worker_Data={
                                                              "User_Name": "myusername",
                                                              "Password": "test#@#@#81"
                                                          }
                                                          )
```